# How to transform terraform-plugin-framework/types package's types.Object and []types.Object to golang struct type in resource

Tags: json, go, struct, terraform, terraform-provider

I am trying to create a terraform provider. And In resource Create method I want to convert the types.Object and []types.Object (from terraform-plugin-framework/types package) to usual Golang struct so I can make a post request to my api.

This is my struct and schema

```
type ClusterDetails struct {
    ID             types.String `tfsdk:"id"`
    Name           types.String `tfsdk:"name"`
    CloudAccountID types.String `tfsdk:"cloud_account_id"`
    CreatedAt      types.String `tfsdk:"created_at"`
    Status         types.String `tfsdk:"status"`

    Firewall   []types.Object `tfsdk:"firewall"`
    NodeGroups types.Object   `tfsdk:"node_groups"`
}

func (r *clusterResource) Schema(_ context.Context, _ resource.SchemaRequest, resp *resource.SchemaResponse) {
    resp.Schema = schema.Schema{
        Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
            "id": schema.StringAttribute{
                Computed:    true,
                Description: "ID of the cluster",
            },
            "name": schema.StringAttribute{
                Required:    true,
                Description: "Name of the cluster",
            },
            "cloud_account_id": schema.StringAttribute{
                Required:    true,
                Description: "Cloud account ID of the cluster",
            },
            "created_at": schema.StringAttribute{
                Computed:    true,
                Description: "Created at of the cluster",
            },
            "status": schema.StringAttribute{
                Computed:    true,
                Description: "Status of the cluster",
            },
            "firewall": schema.ListNestedAttribute{
                Optional: true,
                NestedObject: schema.NestedAttributeObject{
                    Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
                        "type": schema.StringAttribute{
                            Optional:    true,
                            Description: "Type of the firewall rule",
                        },
                        "port": schema.Int64Attribute{
                            Optional:    true,
                            Description: "Port for the firewall rule",
                        },
                        "sources": schema.ListAttribute{
                            ElementType: types.StringType,
                            Optional:    true,
                            Description: "Sources for the firewall rule",
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            "node_groups": schema.SingleNestedAttribute{
                Optional: true,
                Computed: true,
                Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
                    "aws": schema.ListNestedAttribute{
                        Optional: true,
                        NestedObject: schema.NestedAttributeObject{
                            Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
                                "region": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Region of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "availability_zones": schema.ListAttribute{
                                    ElementType: types.StringType,
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Availability zones of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "cidr": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "CIDR of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "public_subnets": schema.ListAttribute{
                                    ElementType: types.StringType,
                                    Optional:    true,
                                },
                                "private_subnets": schema.ListAttribute{
                                    ElementType: types.StringType,
                                    Optional:    true,
                                },
                                "nodes": schema.ListNestedAttribute{
                                    Optional: true,
                                    NestedObject: schema.NestedAttributeObject{
                                        Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
                                            "display_name": schema.StringAttribute{
                                                Optional:    true,
                                                Description: "Display name of the node",
                                            },
                                            "ip_address": schema.StringAttribute{
                                                Optional:    true,
                                                Description: "IP address of the node",
                                            },
                                            "is_active": schema.BoolAttribute{
                                                Optional:    true,
                                                Description: "Is the node active",
                                            },
                                        },
                                    },
                                },
                                "node_location": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Node location of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "volume_size": schema.Int64Attribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Volume size of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "volume_iops": schema.Int64Attribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Volume IOPS of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "volume_type": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Volume type of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "instance_type": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Instance type of the AWS node group",
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    "azure": schema.ListNestedAttribute{
                        Optional: true,
                        NestedObject: schema.NestedAttributeObject{
                            Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
                                "region": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Region of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "availability_zones": schema.ListAttribute{
                                    ElementType: types.StringType,
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Availability zones of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "cidr": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "CIDR of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "public_subnets": schema.ListAttribute{
                                    ElementType: types.StringType,
                                    Optional:    true,
                                },
                                "private_subnets": schema.ListAttribute{
                                    ElementType: types.StringType,
                                    Optional:    true,
                                },
                                "nodes": schema.ListNestedAttribute{
                                    Optional: true,
                                    NestedObject: schema.NestedAttributeObject{
                                        Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
                                            "display_name": schema.StringAttribute{
                                                Optional:    true,
                                                Description: "Display name of the node",
                                            },
                                            "ip_address": schema.StringAttribute{
                                                Optional:    true,
                                                Description: "IP address of the node",
                                            },
                                            "is_active": schema.BoolAttribute{
                                                Optional:    true,
                                                Description: "Is the node active",
                                            },
                                        },
                                    },
                                },
                                "node_location": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Node location of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "volume_size": schema.Int64Attribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Volume size of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "volume_iops": schema.Int64Attribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Volume IOPS of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "volume_type": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Volume type of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "instance_type": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Instance type of the AWS node group",
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    "google": schema.ListNestedAttribute{
                        Optional: true,
                        NestedObject: schema.NestedAttributeObject{
                            Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
                                "region": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Region of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "availability_zones": schema.ListAttribute{
                                    ElementType: types.StringType,
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Availability zones of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "cidr": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "CIDR of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "public_subnets": schema.ListAttribute{
                                    ElementType: types.StringType,
                                    Optional:    true,
                                },
                                "private_subnets": schema.ListAttribute{
                                    ElementType: types.StringType,
                                    Optional:    true,
                                },
                                "nodes": schema.ListNestedAttribute{
                                    Optional: true,
                                    NestedObject: schema.NestedAttributeObject{
                                        Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
                                            "display_name": schema.StringAttribute{
                                                Optional:    true,
                                                Description: "Display name of the node",
                                            },
                                            "ip_address": schema.StringAttribute{
                                                Optional:    true,
                                                Description: "IP address of the node",
                                            },
                                            "is_active": schema.BoolAttribute{
                                                Optional:    true,
                                                Description: "Is the node active",
                                            },
                                        },
                                    },
                                },
                                "node_location": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Node location of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "volume_size": schema.Int64Attribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Volume size of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "volume_iops": schema.Int64Attribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Volume IOPS of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "volume_type": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Volume type of the AWS node group",
                                },
                                "instance_type": schema.StringAttribute{
                                    Optional:    true,
                                    Description: "Instance type of the AWS node group",
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
}
```

This is what the responce for node_groups and firewall look like:

```
var (
    NodesNodeGroupType = map[string]attr.Type{
        "display_name": types.StringType,
        "ip_address":   types.StringType,
        "is_active":    types.BoolType,
    }

    NodeGroupTypes = map[string]attr.Type{
        "region": types.StringType,
        "cidr":   types.StringType,
        "availability_zones": types.ListType{
            ElemType: types.StringType,
        },
        "public_subnets": types.ListType{
            ElemType: types.StringType,
        },
        "private_subnets": types.ListType{
            ElemType: types.StringType,
        },
        "nodes": types.ListType{
            ElemType: types.ObjectType{
                AttrTypes: NodesNodeGroupType,
            },
        },
        "node_location": types.StringType,
        "volume_size":   types.Int64Type,
        "volume_iops":   types.Int64Type,
        "volume_type":   types.StringType,
        "instance_type": types.StringType,
    }

    NodeGroupsTypes = map[string]attr.Type{
        "aws": types.ListType{
            ElemType: types.ObjectType{
                AttrTypes: NodeGroupTypes,
            },
        },
        "azure": types.ListType{
            ElemType: types.ObjectType{
                AttrTypes: NodeGroupTypes,
            },
        },
        "google": types.ListType{
            ElemType: types.ObjectType{
                AttrTypes: NodeGroupTypes,
            },
        },
    }

    firewallElementsType := map[string]attr.Type{
        "type": types.StringType,
        "port": types.Float64Type,
        "sources": types.ListType{
            ElemType: types.StringType,
        },
    }
)
```

Now I need to use this node_groups and firewall in my api request in resources but I cant find a way to decrypt the values to Go's struct type. Heres what my structs and create method looks like:

```
type ClusterCreationRequestNodeGroups struct {

    // aws
    Aws []*NodeGroup `json:"aws"`

    // azure
    Azure []*NodeGroup `json:"azure"`

    // google
    Google []*NodeGroup `json:"google"`
}

type NodeGroup struct {

    // availability zones
    AvailabilityZones []string `json:"availability_zones"`

    // cidr
    Cidr string `json:"cidr,omitempty"`

    // instance type
    InstanceType string `json:"instance_type,omitempty"`

    // node location
    NodeLocation string `json:"node_location,omitempty"`

    // nodes
    Nodes []*NodeGroupNodesItems0 `json:"nodes"`

    // private subnets
    PrivateSubnets []string `json:"private_subnets"`

    // public subnets
    PublicSubnets []string `json:"public_subnets"`

    // region
    Region string `json:"region,omitempty"`

    // volume iops
    VolumeIops int64 `json:"volume_iops,omitempty"`

    // volume size
    VolumeSize int64 `json:"volume_size,omitempty"`

    // volume type
    VolumeType string `json:"volume_type,omitempty"`
}

type NodeGroupNodesItems0 struct {

    // display name
    DisplayName string `json:"display_name,omitempty"`

    // ip address
    IPAddress string `json:"ip_address,omitempty"`

    // is active
    IsActive bool `json:"is_active,omitempty"`
}

type ClusterCreationRequestFirewallRulesItems0 struct {

    // port
    Port int64 `json:"port,omitempty"`

    // sources
    Sources []string `json:"sources"`

    // type
    Type string `json:"type,omitempty"`
}

type ClusterCreationRequestFirewallRulesItems struct {

    // port
    Port int64 `json:"port,omitempty"`

    // sources
    Sources []string `json:"sources"`

    // type
    Type string `json:"type,omitempty"`
}

func (r *clusterResource) Create(ctx context.Context, req resource.CreateRequest, resp *resource.CreateResponse) {
    var plan ClusterDetails
    diags := req.Plan.Get(ctx, &plan)
    resp.Diagnostics.Append(diags...)
    if resp.Diagnostics.HasError() {
        return
    }
```

Comment: This is generally somewhat complex and requires a substantial amount of customized code, and large plugin providers typically use generics to try and DRY. If all of the types were primitives then it would be easier, but you are "serde" slices, maps, and structs. For conversion in either direction it partially involves e.g. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/framework/handling-data/types/set and reference e.g. `ElementsAs` and `SetValueFrom`. You also need a corresponding TFType map for each Go struct.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard Thank you. This is the way I had to solve this issue. Big thanks man.